# Show progress bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

when I'm uploading a file in Chrome, a small status bar message appears on the bottom left of the window, saying Uploading 23%... and so on, until the upload is finished.
How to show Chrome upload progress in html?
[Chrome upload progress pic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NdyD2.jpg)

Comment: Something like this? - http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/